# Do I need an alternative to runnable when using threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

When calling `thread.start()` from my main program the method `run()` is called in the thread like so:

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
        //executable code
        }

        public void myMethod() {
        //code to hopefully respond to a button press in main class.
        }
}
```

I need to call `myMethod` in the existing thread from my main class. But as I understand it, this is not possible using `Runnable`. Is there some other way to do it?

Comment: Why can't you reference the object as a `ServerThread` in your main class?

Comment: This is not clear why run and myMethod are two different methods. But anyway, you can call myMethod in run, if this is what you need. Or maybe you need something totally different, but then you will have give more info to get some help.

Comment: I also cannot see any reason why you would not be able to access that method from any thread, as long as you have a reference to the ServerThread object that you created. It does seem like a weak design to call a method on a running thread from another thread (possibly modifying some thread state). It might be a good idea to look at a different design.

Comment: If myMethod is called in reaction to a button press, it will be executed by the GUI thread, not the server thread.  Once you have two methods of the same object being executed at the same time, there is a strong danger of race conditions. You need to use some safe inter-thread communication method. E.g. monitors, rendezvous, semaphores, etc.

Comment: The reason why you cannot just call method to change object state in java memory model, your thread can not see the changes without synchronization. Also it's generally bad idea to call fat method from main UI thread. If you need to get result from method in reaction of button press, you may use Callable interface.

Comment: I don't see this as particularly weak - it's fairly common.  MyMethod() might well queue up its parameter/s to a private queue that run() waits on.  This implies inter-thread comms, as described by @TheodoreNorvell, but it's certainly not an unusual design - it encapsulates the inter-thread comms nicely.

Comment: I guess I should clarify that I'm setting up a server on one device in order to control several other client devices. I've read that normally clients send messages to the server and get responses. Is this server in control approach that I'm proposing unusual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
ServerThread st = new ServerThread();
new Thread(st).start();
st.myMethod();
```

Comment: This would work only if used proper synchronization i.e. synchronized method, critical sections, or more complex like locks, semaphores etc.

Comment: The question stated: "I need to call myMethod in the existing thread from my main class." This is sufficient to address that need.

Comment: @Dave - yes it is, so +1.  If the OP messes up the thread state by inappropriate action within myMethod, it does not invalidate your answer.

Comment: st needs to be reachable.  Whether this means global or not is up to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class:

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable, ActionListener {

        public void run() {
        //executable code


        }

        void buttonPressed(ActionEvent ae){

      // your event handling code
    }

}
```

change, `ActionListener` and `buttonPressed()` to your framework specific Listener class and event handler.

Comment: But will this work when all my other buttons and listeners are laid out in my main program?

Comment: Yes, event will be notified to all registered listeners